# bash command and return status

Tags: bash

pkill return status > 0  if error ( for example if not found process ). How to return 0 status independing result of pkill ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Either just don't test for the result, or do:

```
pkill whatever || true
```

Comment: +1, or `exit 0` at the end of the script, or last call to `/bin/true` (as you did) ...